# How to use PHP to do image diffs between similarly sized images?

Tags: php, ruby, image, image-processing

I just discovered this article http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/comparing-images-and-creating-image-diffs/

It is talking about using regular Ruby and ChunkyPNG to do image diffs.

In particular, the first code of doing a loop through all the pixels.

```
require 'chunky_png'

images = [
  ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file('1.png'),
  ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file('2.png')
]

diff = []

images.first.height.times do |y|
  images.first.row(y).each_with_index do |pixel, x|
    diff << [x,y] unless pixel == images.last[x,y]
  end
end

puts "pixels (total):     #{images.first.pixels.length}"
puts "pixels changed:     #{diff.length}"
puts "pixels changed (%): #{(diff.length.to_f / images.first.pixels.length) * 100}%"

x, y = diff.map{ |xy| xy[0] }, diff.map{ |xy| xy[1] }

images.last.rect(x.min, y.min, x.max, y.max, ChunkyPNG::Color.rgb(0,255,0))
images.last.save('diff.png')
```

I wonder

a) what would be an ideal PHP equivalent of ChunkyPNG?
b) what would be the implementation of the same code in PHP?

Comment: I know of a way to do image diffs in PHP, but I am really unsure about whether it's the ideal way. It's just the only feasible way I know. Are you interested in such a solution or do you insist on the solution being the ideal one?

Comment: @Oswald Please share. It is better than nothing. Who knows? Maybe your answer may benefit someone else asking similar questions

Comment: i advice you not to build another bicycle, use https://github.com/jenssegers/imagehash perfect lib to gen hash and  compare images by hashes !

Comment: also, id add some image on jpg image, near pixels will be also changes, as colors too! so calculation between 2 images is between 2 hashes, and only you can set what can be differ and what are the same, eve if hash is slightly differ

Answer (score 0):

You can do with Imagick extension. Imagick is a native php extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick API.

Example Using Imagick::compareImages():

Compare images and display the reconstructed image.

```
<?php

$image1 = new imagick("image1.png");
$image2 = new imagick("image2.png");

$result = $image1->compareImages($image2, Imagick::METRIC_MEANSQUAREERROR);
$result[0]->setImageFormat("png");

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $result[0];

?>
```

OR

A PHP shell script to tell you if two images are visually different by comparing them pixel by pixel. If there's a difference, the script creates a third image - black background with the different pixels in green. Here two GD images are created from the input files, also a third GD image with black background to store the diff. Loop through all the pixels and compare them one by one. If one is different, write a green pixel at the same location of the diff image. [Source : http://www.phpied.com/image-diff/ ]

diff.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Shell script to tell if two images are identical.
 * If not, a third image is written - black background with the different pixels painted green
 * Code partially inspired by and borrowed from http://pear.php.net/Image_Text test cases
 */

// check if there's enough input
if (empty($argv[1]) || empty($argv[2])) {
    echo 'gimme at least two image filenames, please.', "\n";
    echo 'e.g. "php idiff.php img1.png img2.png"';
    echo "\n", 'third filename is the image diff, optional, default is "diffy.png"';
    exit(1);
}

// create images
$i1 = @imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($argv[1]));
$i2 = @imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($argv[2]));

// check if we were given garbage
if (!$i1) {
    echo $argv[1] . ' is not a valid image';
    exit(1);
}
if (!$i2) {
    echo $argv[2] . ' is not a valid image';
    exit(1);
}

// dimensions of the first image
$sx1 = imagesx($i1);
$sy1 = imagesy($i1);

// compare dimensions
if ($sx1 !== imagesx($i2) || $sy1 !== imagesy($i2)) {
    echo "The images are not even the same size";
    exit(1);
}

// create a diff image
$diffi = imagecreatetruecolor($sx1, $sy1);
$green = imagecolorallocate($diffi, 0, 255, 0);
imagefill($diffi, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($diffi, 0, 0, 0));

// increment this counter when encountering a pixel diff
$different_pixels = 0;

// loop x and y
for ($x = 0; $x < $sx1; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $sy1; $y++) {

        $rgb1 = imagecolorat($i1, $x, $y);
        $pix1 = imagecolorsforindex($i1, $rgb1);

        $rgb2 = imagecolorat($i2, $x, $y);
        $pix2 = imagecolorsforindex($i2, $rgb2);

        if ($pix1 !== $pix2) { // different pixel
            // increment and paint in the diff image
            $different_pixels++;
            imagesetpixel($diffi, $x, $y, $green);
        }

    }
}


if (!$different_pixels) {
    echo "Image is the same";
    exit(0);
} else {
    if (empty($argv[3])) {
        $argv[3] = 'diffy.png'; // default result filename
    }
    imagepng($diffi, $argv[3]);
    $total = $sx1 * $sy1;
    echo "$different_pixels/$total different pixels, or ", number_format(100 * $different_pixels / $total, 2), '%';
    exit(1);
}
?>
```

Usage (Command line):

php diff.php img1.png img2.png result.png